# File I/O: File is not encoded

Tags: output-formatting, files-and-directories, input

I have a .wl file which should write a number to a .m file (using `Put`), and another .wl file that will later read that number back (using `Get`). This is something that I've done before without issue, so I'm a little confused why I'm now getting the warning:

```
Get::notencode:
   Warning: the file voterPhaseExperiment/pop0.01/dens0.40/convergence.m
     is not encoded.
```

Is this something I need to be concerned about/will it affect my data in any way? The results produced using these non-encoded data appear just fine, but I want to be certain that this isn't a problem. I would also generally like to understand why this is happening, since I've never had this kind of problem writing and reading raw (unencoded) data before.

Comment: We need to see working code that will reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `Get` statement, if you put there a key it will throw this error for not key encoded files.

Here's a small example:

```
Get[StringToStream["1"], "key"]
```

> Get::notencode: Warning: the file String["1"] is not encoded.

So if your package wasn't encoded with a key, drop it from `Get`.